# License of the Linux kernel user space API headers

Tags: licensing, derivative-works, linux-kernel

The Linux kernel is licensed under the GPLv2. The [headers that it exports to user space](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi), however, are not covered by the license. This is documented in the [kernel's licensing rules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/license-rules.html):

> The User-space API (UAPI) header files, which describe the interface
>   of user-space programs to the kernel are a special case. According to
>   the note in the kernel COPYING file, the syscall interface is a clear
>   boundary, which does not extend the GPL requirements to any software
>   which uses it to communicate with the kernel. Because the UAPI headers
>   must be includable into any source files which create an executable
>   running on the Linux kernel, the exception must be documented by a
>   special license expression.

This *special license expression* is a [note](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/LICENSES/exceptions/Linux-syscall-note) that clarifies which files the kernel's license applies to. It is also present in the kernel's [`COPYING` file](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/COPYING).

> NOTE! This copyright does *not* cover user programs that use kernel
>   services by normal system calls - this is merely considered normal use
>   of the kernel, and does *not* fall under the heading of "derived
>   work".

User space code that uses the `/usr/include/linux` headers are not considered derived works. What are the implications of this? Is the use of incompatible licenses allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Note: I am not a lawyer]

When creating a derived work of a GPLv2-licensed piece of software, you must keep the original copyright, and license your own work as GPLv2.

This note helps clear up, or rather, prevent, contention on this point - any program running in user space that merely uses system calls (as opposed, e.g., to adding new system calls or modifying existing ones) is definitely **not** derived work of the kernel, as is not subject to the aforementioned restrictions.