# Distributing GPL OS with proprietary software

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, operating-system

We are looking to distribute an embedded software product using an open-source, GPL3.0 licensed operating system with our non-GPL proprietary software running on it. With normal works, if our code is using a GPL library, our software must also be licensed under GPL. However, since the software we are distributing is not a derivative of the operating system, must we license our software under GPL? Or does this restriction not apply to the software running the proprietary software?

Comment: This is basically the situation with Linux, except Linux is GPL2 licensed, not GPL3. Many of the standard tools in a typical distribution are GPL3 licensed as well.

Comment: @Brandin That's essentially where I'm at right now. I have an embedded system that I want to run on a GPL3.0 licensed linux distro but I'm not sure if keeping the code for the software running in the desktop environment will be violating the license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly fine for you to [make a non-GPL program](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/6451/9558) that runs on Linux.

With a somewhat similar result, Linux [kernel modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721696/2684771) are linked against LGPL code to prevent modules requiring to be GPL. Linus [explained this back in 1995](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Kernel/proprietary-kernel-modules.html) as a deliberate design decision.

When you say "embedded software", you could risk your software becoming part of a single product, look into [TiVoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoization) to see if this could affect your product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently there's no plans on making hardware restricted access to the innards, so I believe we're alright in terms of TiVoization, we were more worried about violating the GPL license by using and distributing the OS, but it seems we'll be alright. Thanks again!